# ios8, AutoLayout not finding top neighbor

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6

It appears that AutoLayout is not finding my top neighbor (Grand Pu Bah). What do you recommend doing to visually set the top constraint to that of the top neighbor vs. the current view.

[image: xcode layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image overlaps with Grand Pu Bah which is causing Auto Layout to not allow Grand Pu Bah as an option. If you move the image further down, you should see Grand Pu Bah as an option. Then tweak the constant (you can select 0, or even negative number for overlap) in the constraint to make the image closer.